# Devise confirmable issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I've been setting up Devise Confirmable for my development environment Rails 4 app.

My initializers/devise.rb looks like:

```
config.mailer_sender = 'please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com'

config.mailer = 'Devise::Mailer'
require 'devise/orm/active_record'

config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :email ]

config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :email ]

config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]

config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10
config.reconfirmable = false

config.password_length = 6..128
config.reset_password_within = 6.hours
```

and my enviroments/development looks like:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "localhost:3000" }
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

When I sign up for an account, in the rails console, it says the mail was sent:

```
Sent mail to mymail@outlook.com (9.9ms)
Date: Sat, 09 Aug 2014 10:18:22 -0600
From: please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com
Reply-To: please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com
To: mymail@outlook.com
```

Yet I've checked my inbox, and no message was sent? If I just type in the url it gave me to confirm, that works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure `SMTP` to really send (that should be in production env preferably) emails. You can configure `smtp` as:

```
# config/production.rb
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => '<domain>',
  :user_name            => '<username>',
  :password             => '<password>',
  :authentication       => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true  }
```

You can read more about [**ActionMailer**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration-for-gmail)

**As your question** is about `development` env. In development and test mode, emails should not got sent really. Devise is saying right that email got sent. If you want to see those emails, you should use one of the email emulators like:

> [MailCatcher](http://mailcatcher.me/)
>
> [LetterOpener](https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener)